# Loop command, piping previous command's output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand that you can use loops in bash to repeat a command a certain amount of times, although it is more conveniently used within bash scripts.

For example, say I have a file that has been compressed several times, and I wish to fully decompress it.

```
cat file.txt | gzip -d | gzip -d | gzip -d
```

This is practical enough for a file that has been compressed 3 times, but it would become unwieldy if the file was compressed, for example, 18 times. How could this be simplified? I want to run the gzip -d command on the previous command's output n times. Is there a way to execute this from the command line?

Comment: Also is there a reason for doing this? Guessing you don't want to run gzip repeatedly and it's just an example?

Comment: I was using it as an example for how you can run a command n times using the previous command's output as the next command's input. I was wondering if it could be done from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with something along those lines (pardon any syntax error, consider this pseudo-code close to bash syntax) :

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 = iterations left
# $2 = final output file
recursive_gzip()
{
  if
    [[ "$1" -gt 0 ]]
  then
    gzip -d | recursive_gzip $(($1 - 1)) "$2"
  else
    gzip -d > "$2"
  fi
}

recursive_gzip 18 "file.txt" <"file.txt.gz"
```

Please note I replaced your `cat` with a redirection.

You could generalize the idea to share the same function for compress / decompress, and actually make it work for an arbitrary command by using it as positional arguments after 2.

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 = iterations left
# $2 = final output file
recursive_pipe()
{
  if
    [[ "$1" -gt 0 ]]
  then
    "${@:3}" | recursive_pipe $(($1 - 1)) "$2" "${@:3}"
  else
    "${@:3}" > "$2"
  fi
}

# Create gzipped file
recursive_pipe 18 "file.txt.gz" gzip <"file.txt"

# Uncompress gzipped file
recursive_pipe 18 "file.txt" gzip -d <"file.txt.gz"
```

Comment: In the second example, the `then` statement should refer to `recursive_pipe` (not enough characters to allow edit)

Comment: @interloper Thanks for catching that, corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

What if you can't remember or wasn't told how often the file was compressed?
You would like to `gunzip` until it is a normal file.
When you do not want to overwrite your original file, making a copy is the easiest thing:

```
tmpfile=/tmp/mightbegz
cp file.txt ${tmpfile}; 
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do 
   echo "Gunzipping Again" 
   mv ${tmpfile} ${tmpfile}.gz
   gunzip -d ${tmpfile}.gz
done
```

The while loop will stop when `gzip` can not `gunzip` the file.